# Google scripts optimization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mathematical-optimization

I wrote a Google script to optimize a mathematical programming problem, but I can't figure out how to display the optimal solution in the spreadsheet utilizing the optimization script.

Here's the Google script:

```
function myFunction() {
    var engine = LinearOptimizationService.createEngine();

    // Add variables, constraints and define the objective with addVariable(), addConstraint(), etc.
    // Add two variables, 0 <= x <= 10 and 0 <= y <= 5
    engine.addVariable('x', 0, 10);
    engine.addVariable('y', 0, 5);

    // Create the constraint: 0 <= 2 * x + 5 * y <= 10
    var constraint = engine.addConstraint(0, 10);
    constraint.setCoefficient('x', 2);
    constraint.setCoefficient('y', 5);

    // Create the constraint: 0 <= 10 * x + 3 * y <= 20
    var constraint = engine.addConstraint(0, 20);
    constraint.setCoefficient('x', 10);
    constraint.setCoefficient('y', 3);

    // Set the objective to be x + y
    engine.setObjectiveCoefficient('x', 1);
    engine.setObjectiveCoefficient('y', 1);

    // Engine should maximize the objective
    engine.setMaximization();

    // Solve the linear program
    var solution = engine.solve();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the task that you are trying to achieve? Do you want to serialize the solution variable into a spreadsheet? Do you want to stream the output into a file? What attempts have you made? What was the result etc.?

Comment: I want to send the solution values to the spreadsheet calling the function.  I tried using google scripts solution.getvariable and solution.getobjectivefunction calls and return calls and nothing was shown in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

The complete working code is provided below. You need to add a function to write your solution to the active spreadsheet. For that, I have added a new function `addSolution(solution)` which then writes each member of the `solution` object to their respective cells.

```or-tag-here
function myFunction() {
     var engine = LinearOptimizationService.createEngine();

    // Add variables, constraints and define the objective with addVariable(), addConstraint(), etc.
   // Add two variables, 0 <= x <= 10 and 0 <= y <= 5
     engine.addVariable('x', 0, 10);
     engine.addVariable('y', 0, 5);

   // Create the constraint: 0 <= 2 * x + 5 * y <= 10
     var constraint = engine.addConstraint(0, 10);
     constraint.setCoefficient('x', 2);
     constraint.setCoefficient('y', 5);

    // Create the constraint: 0 <= 10 * x + 3 * y <= 20
     var constraint = engine.addConstraint(0, 20);
     constraint.setCoefficient('x', 10);
     constraint.setCoefficient('y', 3);

    // Set the objective to be x + y
     engine.setObjectiveCoefficient('x', 1);
     engine.setObjectiveCoefficient('y', 1);

    // Engine should maximize the objective
     engine.setMaximization();

   // Solve the linear program
     var solution = engine.solve();
     addProduct(solution)
}

function addSolution(solution) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([solution.getObjectiveValue(), solution.getStatus(), solution.getVariableValue('x'), solution.getVariableValue('y'),solution.isValid()]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: @user7686691please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, once you have decided it has solved your problem.